# How to populate database values in table

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to fetch my records in my **users** table and populate them in table if the input is correct using Raw SQL Queries. Trying this convert from SQL to Laravel Queries:

`SELECT * FROM`users`WHERE username = 'shadow'`

Unfortunately it gives me a error.

> Undefined variable: users (View: C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\resources\views\account\search.blade.php)

Controller:

**User** is my Model which has a `protected $table = 'users` which is my database.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
  public function getEmployee()
  {
    return view ('account.search');
  }

  public function postEmployee(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|alpha|max:20',
    ]);

    $username = $request['username']; //Input will be passed to $request array. Accessing search field.

    $user = new User();
    $user = DB::select('select * from users where username = ?', [1]);

    return view ('account.search', ['user' => 'myuser']);

    }
}
```

View:

```
@section ('content')
<div class = "col-md-10">
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.search') }}">

<div class = "form-group {{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

    <label for = "username" class = "control-label">Search</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Find people">

    @if ($errors->has('username'))
        <span class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>

    @endif

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Search</button>

</div>

<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>

<table class = "table">
    <br>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Middlename</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    </thead>


    <tbody>
    @foreach ($user as $myuser)
        <tr class = "success">
            <td>{{ $myuser->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $myuser->first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $myuser->last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $myuser->middle_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $myuser->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $myuser->username }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Archive</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
@endsection
```

[image: Screens]

Routes:

```
Route::get('/search',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@getEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.search',
]);

Route::post('/search',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@postEmployee',
]);
```

Comment: Don't you need to return the $user from your function showEmployee

Comment: I'm just checking if the data is exist.

Comment: DB::select does not return `null` on an empty result. It will return an empty array.

Comment: When Debugging what is the value of $user before your if and after select - you need to determine what is being returned. This will let you know if you have an issue with your query or your code. Just looking at your code - your query is not getting the argument to search for '?' and it might be returning the first result.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->get();

if ($user->isEmpty()) {
    dd('Failed');
else {
    dd('Success');
}
```

Comment: It says undefine variable username.

Comment: well you need to replace $username with the username or assign that variable from the request.

Comment: @Francisunoxx what is not working about it? Are you not hitting failed or success, have you dd'd that you've assigned $username to an actual username?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a model, there is no need for DB::select. You would find a User by their username like so:

```
$user = User::where('username', '=', (the username))->get();
```

Comment: You don't need the '=' either and that piece of code returns a query builder which technically means it will never be null.

Comment: Forgot to add the get() method at the end. That will return the collection.

Comment: That still won't work since it returns a collection. `is_null($user)` will return `false` even when the username doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not answering the is null part, I'm answering the title of the post 'DB::select won't fetch record in database' and his first sentence 'I can't fetch my record in database.'. My answer fixes the 'can't fetch' problem.

Comment: Not really. The only difference is that here you'll get a Collection while using `DB::select`, you'll get an array of records. Other than that, why answer half the question without specifying that you are doing so?